# Combining multiple IF/AND/THEN statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2013, worksheet-function

Working within Excel 2013:

Scenario: automated calculation to fill R11:R61 to determine whether trade is a "Win" or "Loss".
Criteria: determine if long or short, determine if exit price is <>= to Target Price;

I have written the necessary calculation in sentence form to help see the issue. I am struggling with combining the two ideas into one.

> IF a trade (D11:D61) = "long" AND the Exit Price (M11:M61) is >= Target Price (N11:N61) THEN (R11:R61) = "Win" otherwise "Loss"
>
> IF the above trade = "short" AND the Exit Price (M11:M61) is <= Target Price (N11:N61) THEN (R11:R61) = "Win" otherwise "Loss"

Is there a way to combine the two calculation IF/THEN scenarios into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
=IF(OR(AND(D11="long",M11>=N11),AND(D11="short",N11>=M11)),"Win","Loss")
```

Comment: I was all over the place and extremely close, but you have been a huge help.  I had to tweak your original calculation to make it work.  Here is what I found successful... =IF(OR(AND($D$11="Long",$M$11>=N11),AND($D$11="Short",$M$11<=N11)),"Win","Loss")

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks for catching that for me.  That was just my test line.

Comment: @pnuts...ran into a bit of trouble and didn't know if you might have a solution.  I found that I must have the field remain blank if D11 is blank... otherwise, the field plots a "Loss" automatically.  Is there a way to add an additional criteria to...  =IF(OR(AND($D11="Long",$M11>=$N11),AND($D11="Short",$M11<=$N11)),"Win","Loss") without messing up the overall calculation?   This works brilliantly, but need a blank when D11 is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If ((trade (D11:D61) = "long" AND the Exit Price (M11:M61) is >= Target Price (N11:N61) ) 
   OR (trade = "short" AND the Exit Price (M11:M61) is <= Target Price (N11:N61))) then "Win" otherwise "Loss"

Now to get this into Excel formula form...